# Invalid parameter on FullSeriesCollection

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Hi I'm taking back the lead on a project for an Excel plugin. But I ran into a kind of strange error:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Parameter not valid at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Chart.FullSeriesCollection(Object Index)`

The corresponding line is:

```
chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.ShowValue = true;
```

Any idea of what's wrong in there?

Comment: You asked for the first item in the collection. Does the collection contain *any* items?